# Jquery Ajax: display jquery animation if user IP is blocked and form is not submitted to SQL table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

For testing purposes, I have a simple form that asks for generic info but the user can only enter info once. Their IP address is recorded so if they try to enter info again, the data does not get sent to the SQL table. I am using Jquery Ajax for form submission. If the form is submitted successfully, the message "Information submitted." should be shown. If the user's IP is matched against the IP that is recorded, the message "You only get to submit once." is shown.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to get the jquery ajax to display the "You only get to submit once." message after the IP address detected is matched against IP address in database.
It doesn't have to use "error: function()..."

Here is the form and Jquery Ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {

    var words     = $('#words').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getuser.php",
            data: "words="+ words, 
            success: function(){
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
                },
            error: function(){
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.fail').fadeIn();});
                }

        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>


<form id="submit" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Enter Information</legend>

<label for="words">words:</label>
<input id="words" class="text" name="words" size="20" type="text">

            <button> Submit </button>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div class="success" style="display: none;">Information submitted.</div>
</div>
<div class="fail" style="display: none;">You only get to submit once.</div>
```

Here is the PHP script:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("","","");
    mysql_select_db("");

//take IP address and match IP taken with IP in SQL table (I will do this myself later)

//if IPs match
if ($ip == $databaseIP)
{
   die();
}
else
{
        $words      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['words']));

        $addClient  = "INSERT INTO test VALUES('','$words')";
        mysql_query($addClient) or die(mysql_error());
}    
?>
```

UPDATE: here is the PHP equivalent of what I want

```
 if ( $_POST['words']  )
    {

 if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }    
        $ipquery = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM rate WHERE ip = '$ip' ");
        $ipquery = mysql_fetch_assoc($ipquery);
        $ipquery = $ipquery['ip'];

        if ($ipquery == $ip)
        {       
            echo "you only get to submit once";
        }
        else
        {
        mysql_query ("INSERT INTO rate VALUES ('','$words')");          

        echo "information submitted";   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If your PHP script returns an HTTP error when the IP is found, then your code should work.
Not sure if die() returns and error response though.</strike>

I see.
I have something similar.
This is what my PHP returns

```
if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
    echo $success ? "success" : "error";
}
```

And my AJAX handler:

```
  $.ajax( {
    url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
    type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
    data: contactForm.serialize(),
    success: submitFinished
  } );

function submitFinished( response ) {
  response = $.trim( response );

  if ( response == "success" ) {

    ...

  } else {

    ...
  }
}
```

This should get you what you need.

**Edit:**
New answer.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {

    var words     = $('#words').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getuser.php",
            data: "words="+ words, 
            success: function(response){
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.status').append(response).fadeIn();});
                },
            error: function(){
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.status').append("Error while processing request.").fadeIn();});
                }

        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I didn't test this, but this should work for your case.

Comment: It doesn't have to use "error: function()" I just need the script to  tell the user "You only get to submit once." if their IP was recorded in the SQL table.

Comment: please see my updated OP for clearer explanation of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I am still pretty new to Jquery Ajax and Ajax in general. Could you please explain your example in terms of the Jquery Ajax and PHP script I provided?

Answer (score 1):

I would re-do your methodology here. Have the PHP return a string, either `You have submitted` or `You have already done this, please stop submitting. Now. No really, stop.` Then, in your `success` function, set that to be the text (`val()`) of the success div.

Comment: please see my updated OP for clearer explanation of what I'm trying to do.